# get value of hidden input field in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, input, field, hidden

I have a charts program that works in js, but I need to update excels with the data using c#. So, what I've done so far is to create hidden input fields whose values are updated with the js variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="baselineInput"  id="baselineVariable" />
<input type="hidden" name="goalInput" runat="server" id="goalVariable" />
<input type="hidden" name="currentInput" runat="server" id="currentVariable" />

//do some things here
var MTDGauge = new Array(5,5,5);

document.getElementById("baselineVariable").value = MTDGauge[0];
document.getElementById("goalVariable").value = MTDGauge[1];
document.getElementById("currentVariable").value = MTDGauge[2];
```

The problem I'm having is reading these values back to the c# variable. Here's what I've tried (placed after the code above):

```
    List<string> OverallData = new List<string>();

    OverallData.Add(Request["baselineInput"]);
    OverallData.Add(Request["goalInput"]);
    OverallData.Add(Request["currentInput"]);
```

This is just adding null values (assuming so because the c# is loading before the javascript and the initialized values for the text fields are null?). I thought of creating a c# function that could be called using the onchange option in the input field, but that didn't get me anywhere. Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to do a post?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to get your data back to the server (where your C# is running) you need to send it back.

POST is one way, or GET to add the values to the query string.

Javascript is only running in the browser, until you send something back to the server, your ASP.NET app will not have any information.

Of course, if you want to do it asynchronously you could use jQuery.ajax to send the data to a server URL without refreshing the whole page.